# difference between org.w3c.dom.Document and org.dom4j.Document

Tags: java, domparser

why we need this two Document

`1) org.w3c.dom.Document 2) org.dom4j.Document`

What is difference between this two ?

```
public static org.dom4j.Document getDom4jDocument(Document w3cDocument)
    {
        //System.out.println("XMLUtility : Inside getDom4jDocument()");
        org.dom4j.Document dom4jDocument  = null;
        DOMReader xmlReader  = null;
        try{
            //System.out.println("Before conversion of w3cdoc to dom4jdoc");
            xmlReader = new DOMReader();            
            dom4jDocument = xmlReader.read(w3cDocument);
            //System.out.println("Conversion complete");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("General Exception :- "+e.getMessage());
        }
        //System.out.println("XMLUtility : getDom4jDocument() Finished");
        return dom4jDocument;   
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.w3c.dom.Document` is standard API on Java SE while `org.dom4j.Document` is for Dom4J. There are not compatible with each other.

You don't need the 2, it depends on your flavour. Some prefer using Dom4J and some stick to the standard Java SE API.

Comment: I am getting stackoverflowerror while converting org.w3c.dom.Document to org.dom4j.Document. I edited the question for this conversion.

Comment: @chetan, now you're asking a totally different question. Either edit this post or ask a new question on SO.